# Assigning multiple variables in matlab from one matrix

Tags: matlab, csv, variables

I need to write this csv to have more than one output but do not know how to either do that or assign each number to a separate variable and then have that print in a list for the csv file.

```
x=rand(10);
for rows=[1:10]; 
    for cols=[1:10]
        j=x(rows,cols)
    end
end 
csvwrite('weikle_list1.csv',j);
y=csvread('weikle_list1.csv') 
for cols=[1:10]
    for rows=[1:10]
        k=x(cols,rows)
    end
end
csvwrite('weikle_list2.csv',k);
w=csvread('weikle_list2.csv')
formatspec='k=%1.4f'; 
fprintf(formatspec,x);
```

Comment: Why not just `csvwrite('weikle_list1.csv', x);`?

Comment: I would love to but I am suppose to have the list print out with the new variables if thats even  possible...

Comment: @N.Weikle That makes no sense. I'm guessing you're completely misunderstanding the assignment.

Comment: 1) Create a random matrix. 
2) Create nested loops to read the random data one by one by rows then columns and to assign these data to a new variable
3) Write to a csv file.
4) Read from the csv file to another variable.
5) Transpose, and then reverse the nested loops to read by columns and then rows and to assign the data to a final variable.
6) Write the data to a second csv file.

Comment: Okay, in the first loop, change to `j(rows, cols) = x(rows, cols);`

Comment: You don't need loops `j = x;` and `k = x;` is enough.

Comment: thank you all! it works perfectly now!